# Comparator Implementation

Tags: java, comparative-review

I am trying to compare Entries by their frequencies using Comparator. I wanna know if this piece of code would work for this case?

```
    // Creates entries
private class Entry {
    private String word;
    private long count;

    public Entry(String w, long c) {
        word = w;
        count = c;
    }

    public String getWord() { return word; }
    public long getCount() { return count; }

    public Entry(String entry) {
        String parts[] = entry.split("\t");
        word = parts[1].trim();
        count = new Long(parts[0].trim());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + word + "," + count + ")";
    }

}

    // compare Entry objects by their frequencies
private static Comparator<Entry> countComparator() {
    return new Comparator<Entry>() {
        public int compare(Entry e1, Entry e2) {
            if(e1.getCount() > e2.getCount()) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(e1.getCount() < e2.getCount()) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `Entry(String)` and `Entry.toString` seems irrelevant for the question.

Comment: `Comparator.comparingLong(Entry::getCount)` would be the shorter equivalent in Java 8+.

Comment: @4castle you can post that as an answer (and you should get at least as many points as me). Otherwise I'll take it over in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The comparator should work fine, however `return Integer.compare(int, int)` avoid the re-invention of the wheel.